# How to define div specific script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple div's inside my HTML, basically I have defined multiple tabs inside my HTML. I am using a script tag inside one of the tab to display some data. But it leaves that specific div and goes out of the div and permanently displayed after all the tabs.

```
<div class="tabs-pane active-pane" id="actors" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="text-align:center;">
  <div class="aui-page-panel-inner">
    <div class="aui-page-panel-nav">
      <script>
        display_data_new();
        myfunction();
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are making a document.write() this is your problem. If not, I don't know what are you doing, I'm not wizard.

Comment: It's really not good practice to put `<script>` tags in the middle of the HTML like that.

Comment: Those two functions are displaying data in tabular format. But the problem is, it is not going inside the specific tab where I have defined script tag.

Comment: @SteveCrocHunter: Is there a way I can call those functions form the specific div or restrict the function to a specific div.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume that the data you have in those functions is formatted into `html` - there are numerous tutorials on the web about this.

Try this:

```
 (function() {

   var loadData = function(){
       var contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
       contentDiv.appendChild(display_data_new()) ;
       contentDiv.appendChild(myFunction());
   }

   window.onload = loadData();
  })();
```

This is going to execute when the window has finished loading.  The function grabs the `content` DOM element and will append the code from your `display_data_new()` and `myFunction()` functions to it.

I suggest reading about the DOM:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

It's fundamental to understand this in order to use JavaScript to manipulate HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing towards right concept.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever script is written inside the  tag is executed immediately. So of course it is shown always, regardless of your current 'tab'.

If you REALLY need to have the  tag inside that , then you should add some condition inside it.

something like this

```
 <script>
  if (currentTabId == 'DivWithScript') {
    display_data_new();
    myfunction();
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: <script>
      if ('#actors') {
               display_data_new();
               myfunction();
       }
</script>          I tried with this but it's still the same.

Comment: @user2900150 `if ('#actors') ` evaluates string, which has "truthy" value. Truthy value evalues to true. In other words: your condition is always true. You need to store ID of currently shown div/tab and then check if this ID is equal to `actors`

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try below `code` -

```
    <div class="tabs-pane active-pane" id="actors" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false" style="text-align:center;">
       <div class="aui-page-panel-inner">
          <div class="aui-page-panel-nav">
             <div id="content">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function myFunction() {
                       //do something
                    }
                    myFunction();
                </script>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```